# Distributing .Net Windows Forms Application publicly (ClickOnce alternatives)

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a small windows forms application that I'm currently distributing via clickonce. I'm finding that I have a lot of hoops to jump through to get the click once installer branded with my logo via an automated build and am thinking about going with Squirrel for distribution as it seems to offer more control over how updates are performed.

I was wondering what other alternatives there might be that I'm not seeing. What is the standard mechanism for distributing apps that will have somewhat frequent updates.

Comment: Hard to see what a "logo" could be useful for.  Boilerplate is that the user visits a URL to get the installer, a web page is a pretty good place to splatter pixels.  Don't help too much, ClickOnce already knows how to automatically retrieve updates.

Comment: Not a terribly helpful comment. We want the setup.exe that is created by click once to have our logo on it so it looks more professional.  We can sign it through automation but adding the logo to it is a pain.  Thus why I"m asking about alternatives.